# class diagram one-to-many association

Tags: visual-studio

How to set up in Class Diagram one-to-many association between classes People and Car like on this picture: 
[image]

For example when I simply create an association between two classes I receive one-to-one relation, when I create property Cars with type List and then apply "Show as Collection Association" I get an error "Cannot show as association because List cannot be found...", how to make one-to-many association?

Comment: how are you crating your List? is that a List<Car> ? or you are just typing List?

Comment: You need to use the fully qualified name for the list type, so instead of list use system.collections.generic<list>